# Lynx, amazon.com and cookies

Tags: web, cookies, browser, lynx

When trying to use the lynx web browser (version 2.8.8dev12) I'm running into a problem with cookies. Whenever I try to check out (order with 1-click) I am asked to enable cookies. I have accepted all cookies, but it doesn't seem to be sending them. I found an old bug report with this problem from 2008, but while it says it has been fixed I'm still running into it.

I used sudo apt-get install lynx on raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason if I uncheck send useragent and use amazon.com/access everything works.